# Can I build a blob in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a scenario where a db has a few hundred million rows, keeping a history of a few weeks only.

In this database are different products (tradable instruments) and each has about 72k rows of data per hour and there is roughly 30 products.

The data is always requested by blocks of 1h, aligned on 1h. For example "I want data for X from 2pm to 3pm.

This data is processed by several tools and the requests are very demanding for the database.

Each tool does its own disk caching, building a binary blob for each hour.

But I was wondering if it would be possible to build these directly in Postgres?
Data is indexed by timestamp and is written in a linear fashion as the writes represent live data.
So it would be possible to detect with a trigger that we just crossed an hour.

Would it be possible when we detect this to get all this data, build a binary blob out of it and save it in it own table? the data is simply all the columns one after another in binary forms. They're all numbers, no strings, etc so the alignment / format is very simple and rigid.

In practice the rows are like this:

```
instrument     VARCHAR                     NOT NULL,
ts             TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
quantity       FLOAT8                      NOT NULL,
price          FLOAT8                      NOT NULL,
direction      INTEGER                     NOT NULL
```

and I would like, at the end of each hour to build a byte array that's like this:

```
    0  4       12    20         24
    |ts|quantity|price|direction|ts|quantity|price|direction...
```

with every row of the hour. Build one blob per instrument and write it in a table like this:

```
instrument    VARCHAR
ts            TIMESTAMP
blob          BYTEA
```

My questions are:

1. is this possible? or would be it be very inefficient to get 30 (products) * 72k rows each to aggregate and save every hour in an efficient way?
2. is there anywhere I could find an example leading me toward this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I always looked at a blob as a mass of things glued together (like in the movie "the blob"), so I was picturing a binary blob :). Ok, so my question is about making a blob in the db. I'll edit the title

Comment: The data type that matches the SQL standard's `BLOB` ( **B**inary **L**arge **OB**ject)  in Postgres is `bytea`. But I am not sure what your question is. How exactly do you expect a set of columns to be converted into some binary representation?

Comment: I'm writing rows every few ms, when one hour is complete I'd like to know if it's possible to write a procedure that loads all the rows from the last hour, builds a byte array with all the data from each column for that hour and write it to a table; I tried to make the question more clear.

Comment: I don't think that will gain you anything. Small queries like that should be fast when indexed properly. Consider using partitioning to get rid of old data.

Comment: in this case we're having timeout issues because sometime we need a few hours on all products, so if I request 4 hours on 30 products, that's 4 * 30 * 72k rows to return. My assumption is that if I can reduce that to 4 * 30 * blob it would perform better. You think the performance will remain similar?

Comment: I don't get it. The values of the columns are already stored as some kind of "blob" on disk. What do you expect to gain from duplicating this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name to return a single row (the blob) vs. 72k rows for each query

Comment: Why not simply store the result of the aggregation into a separate table? `insert into aggregate (...) select sum(c1), avg(c2) ... from the_table where ... group by ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the client needs all the rows, but the query will always return them by blocks of 72k, so my assumption is that if they'd be grouped in the db as a blob, I could just return that one blob and let the client parse it. Since there are several clients, the savings are multiplied as well